# Download latest files during installation Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin, inno-tools-downloader

Is it possible to script that during installation to download files from a web server with Inno Setup?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer as InnoTools Downloader, recommended by the currently accepted answer, has not been updated since 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the InnoTools Downloader (http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50).

Comment: InnoTools Downloader, has not been updated since 2008. It does not work with the latest version of Inno Setup anymore.

Answer (score 3):

*InnoTools Downloader, recommended by the accepted answer, has not been updated since 2008. It does not work with Unicode version of Inno Setup (so it does not work with Unicode-only Inno Setup 6) and does not support HTTPS (among other). Do not use it.*

---

Use [Inno Setup 6.1](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6-whatsnew.htm) built-in support for downloads. See [Install file from Internet in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887428/850848#66100456).

---

*An old answer (before Inno Setup 6.1): I'm re-posting the answer by @Jens A. Koch, which has been deleted:*

You might use the **[Inno Download Plugin](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/)** by Mitrich Software.

- It's an Inno Setup script and DLL, which allows you to download files as part of your installation.
- It supports FTP, HTTP and HTTPS.
- It's kind of a drop-in replacement for InnoTools Downloader. Only few changes required.
- It brings a decent download display and **HTTPS** and **Mirror(s)** support.

---

There's also [DwinsHs (Downloader for Inno Setup)](https://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php).