# Install file from Internet in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin, inno-tools-downloader

I am using Inno Setup to distribute my application.

Is it possible to check in Inno Script for a particular condition and download and install some file from internet if required?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a library called [InnoTools Downloader](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50) which has samples that do pretty much this. They can be conditioned on anything you want using normal Inno code.

Comment: InnoTools Downloader is dead (not maintained + does not support Unicode Inno Setup + does not support HTTPS + etc). Use Inno Download Plugin instead, as shown in the answer by @Jens.

Comment: And now, Inno Setup 6.1 supports downloads natively. So no 3rd party solution is needed. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887428/850848#66100456).

Answer (score 23):

[Inno Setup 6.1](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6-whatsnew.htm) and newer has a built-in support for downloads. No 3rd party solution is needed anymore.

Check the [`Examples\CodeDownloadFiles.iss`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Examples/CodeDownloadFiles.iss) in Inno Setup installation folder.

The important parts of the example are:

```
[Files]
; These files will be downloaded
Source: "{tmp}\innosetup-latest.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
Source: "{tmp}\ISCrypt.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  DownloadPage: TDownloadWizardPage;

function OnDownloadProgress(const Url, FileName: String; const Progress, ProgressMax: Int64): Boolean;
begin
  if Progress = ProgressMax then
    Log(Format('Successfully downloaded file to {tmp}: %s', [FileName]));
  Result := True;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DownloadPage := CreateDownloadPage(SetupMessage(msgWizardPreparing), SetupMessage(msgPreparingDesc), @OnDownloadProgress);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpReady then begin
    DownloadPage.Clear;
    DownloadPage.Add('https://jrsoftware.org/download.php/is.exe', 'innosetup-latest.exe', '');
    DownloadPage.Add('https://jrsoftware.org/download.php/iscrypt.dll', 'ISCrypt.dll', '2f6294f9aa09f59a574b5dcd33be54e16b39377984f3d5658cda44950fa0f8fc');
    DownloadPage.Show;
    try
      try
        DownloadPage.Download;
        Result := True;
      except
        SuppressibleMsgBox(AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage), mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    finally
      DownloadPage.Hide;
    end;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;
```

[image]

---

For alternatives, see [Running a program after it is downloaded in Code section in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40679399/850848).

Answer (score 16):

**[Inno Download Plugin](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/)** by Mitrich Software.

- It's an InnoSetup script and DLL, which allows you to download files as part of your installation.
- It supports FTP, HTTP and HTTPS.
- It's kind of a drop-in replacement for InnoTools Downloader. Only few changes required.
- It brings a decent download display and **HTTPS** and **Mirror(s)** support.

---

Example:

```
#include <idp.iss>

[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\file.zip"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external; ExternalSize: 1048576

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  idpAddFileSize('http://127.0.0.1/file.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\file.zip'), 1048576);

  idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end.
```

Comment: I would prefer Inno Download Plugin mentioned here before InnoTools Downloader.

Answer (score 2):

Found on [Inno 3rd Party](http://www.jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php) is one very similar in scope and style to the Inno Download Plugin, [DWinsHs](http://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php).
Included with an easy and intuitive chm file which requires [unblocking](https://superuser.com/questions/129915/downloaded-chm-is-blocked-is-there-a-solution) to view.

Comment: Please note: link only answers are discouraged - they turn useless when the links break. And links tend to break. Often.