# How to download and install .net framework 4.5 using silent installer in innosetup?

Tags: wcf, inno-setup

I want to check whether .net framework 4.5 available in end-user PC.If not it should download and install the .net framework 4.5 from this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653 ,using innosetup with silent installer...

Actually i followed this link http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=.NET_-_Detect_framework ,but in this link it takes to web browser page and downloading is happening, i want to download and install the .net framework 4.5 within innosetup wizard itself,it should happen like silent installation.

How to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Use Inno Setup ITDDownload plug-in for this purpose: [Inno setup: Install file from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887428/inno-setup-install-file-from-internet)

The code for detecting .NET framework is fine but instead of executing browser:

```
ShellExec('open', 'http://download/.../dotnetfx.exe','','',SW_SHOWNORMAL,ewNoWait,ErrorCode);
```

download the file (.exe) into some directory and run it:

```
function ITD_DownloadFile(const url, filename: string): boolean;
function Exec(const Filename, Params, WorkingDir: String; const ShowCmd: Integer; const Wait: TExecWait; var ResultCode: Integer): Boolean;
```

Use procedures above - they require some initialization (you can finf it in ITD example  (I am writing from my head)

Comment: The above method seems to be downloading and installing the file manually by user.I want Innosetup to download and install the .net framework 4.5 automatically without user interaction for downloading and installing the .net framework 4.5.