# Running a program after it is downloaded in Code section in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

How do I run an application I have downloaded over the Internet, in the code section using, and also wait for that application to finish running. I have, using InnoTools downloader, downloaded these two files and I want to, after the second one is done downloading to run that download, or `jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe`, then continue the installation.

```pascal
[Code] 

procedure InitializeWizard(); 
begin 
     ITD_Init;

     ITD_AddFile('http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M13/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13-windows-x64.zip', expandconstant('{tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13-windows-x64.zip'));

     ITD_DownloadAfter(1); 

     ITD_AddFile('http://files.downloadnow-1.com/s/software/15/62/36/39/jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe?token=1479511171_b51e94edd4e002c94fd60a570a7dd270&fileName=jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe',expandconstant('{tmp}\jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe'));

     ITD_DownloadAfter(2);       
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

[Inno Setup 6.1](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6-whatsnew.htm) supports downloads natively. See [Install file from Internet in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887428/850848#66100456).

---

If you are stuck with an older version of Inno Setup, use the  [Inno Download Plugin (IDP)](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/), not ITD (see below for reasons).

When you include `idp.iss`, it defines a global `IDPForm` structure. Its `Page` field is the `TWizardPage`, representing a download page. Use its ID in the `NextButtonClick` to run the downloaded file, once the download finishes (the "Next" button on the download page is "pressed" automatically):

```pascal
#include <idp.iss>

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  idpAddFile(
    'https://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M13/bin/' +
      'apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13-windows-x64.zip',
    ExpandConstant('{tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13-windows-x64.zip'));
  idpAddFile(
    'https://www.example.com/jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe',
    ExpandConstant('{tmp}\jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe'));
  idpDownloadAfter(wpSelectDir);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  FileName: string;
begin
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    FileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe');
    Result := Exec(FileName, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

    if not Result then
    begin
      MsgBox('Cannot execute sub-installer', mbError, MB_OK);
    end
      else
    begin
      Result := (ResultCode = 0);
      if not Result then
      begin
        MsgBox('Sub-installer failed', mbError, MB_OK);
      end
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

---

There's also [DwinsHs (Downloader for Inno Setup)](https://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php).

---

While you can implement the same using InnoTools Downloader, you should avoid it:

- It's outdated and not maintained anymore;
- Does not support Unicode Inno Setup (do not use Ansi Inno Setup for new projects);
- Does not support HTTPS;
- Its download page [does not scale on high DPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfA4k.png).

Anyway, for completeness: the `ITD_DownloadAfter` returns `TWizardPage`, representing a download page. Use its ID in the `NextButtonClick` to run the downloaded file, once the download finishes (the "Next" button on the download page is "pressed" automatically):

```pascal
var
  DownloadPage: TWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard(); 
begin 
  ITD_Init;
  ITD_AddFile(
    'http://www.example.com/jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe',
    ExpandConstant('{tmp}\jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe'));
  DownloadPage := ITD_DownloadAfter(wpSelectDir); 
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = DownloadPage.ID then
  begin
    Result :=
      Exec(
        ExpandConstant('{tmp}\jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe'),
        '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

    if not Result then
    begin
      MsgBox('Cannot execute sub-installer', mbError, MB_OK);
    end
      else
    begin
      Result := (ResultCode = 0);
      if not Result then
      begin
        MsgBox('Sub-installer failed', mbError, MB_OK);
      end
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```