# Download additional files based on contents of first download using IDP

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

Want to download files based on contents of first download using Inno Download Plugin (IDP). How to do that?

Here is my code

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  line: string;
  line2: string;
  url: string;
  appname: string;
begin
  idpAddFile('http://download.website.com/files.txt', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\files.txt'));
  idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
  TryGetFileLine(expandConstant('{tmp}\files.txt'), 0, line);
  TryGetFileLine(expandConstant('{tmp}\files.txt'), 1, line2);
  url := line;
  appname := line2;    
  idpAddFile(url, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\'+appname));
  idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

Here second file starts downloading before the first file finishes. So how to make it one after another?

Comment: I do not think that IDP supports parallel downloads. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl then how to download multiple files one after another? any help..

Comment: Your code *does download the two files one after another*.

Comment: nope it is not happening! second file starts downloading before the first one finishes.

Comment: i used `idpStopDownload` and `idpStartDownload` as well but no luck.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing that?

Comment: yes, screenshot has been attached above, please have a look and the status is `cannot connect`

Comment: OK, I understand now. You want to download one file, read its contents and download other files based on that. -- The problem is not that the files are not downloaded one after another - They are. -- The problem is that you incorrectly believe that your `TryGetFileLine` code happens *after* the download of he first file. It does not! All your code happens even before the wizard window appears.

Comment: yes,you are right, based on the first downloaded file's contents the second files have to download. Then how to make `TryGetFileLine` wait till it finishes downloading or any other way to read the content of the downloaded files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell IDP to only download the list initially. Then wait for the download to finish (for that see [Running a program after it is downloaded in Code section in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40679399/850848)) and based on the results, create new download list and restart the download.

```pascal
var
  ListDownloaded: Boolean;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  idpAddFile('http://www.example.com/files.txt', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\files.txt'));
  idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
  ListDownloaded := False;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Url, AppName: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    if not ListDownloaded then
    begin
      TryGetFileLine(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\files.txt'), 0, Url);
      TryGetFileLine(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\files.txt'), 1, AppName);

      idpClearFiles;
      idpAddFile(Url, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + AppName));
      idpFormActivate(nil); { This restarts the download }
      Result := False;
      ListDownloaded := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```