# Do not prevent installation if download fails with Inno Download Plugin

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

This is the code used to download any prerequisites during the installation,

```pascal
#include <idp.iss>

[Code]
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
  idpAddFileSize('<url>', ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\<my file name>'), <my file size>);
  idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

However, if there is no internet connection it disables the Next button from continuing the installation. Here is the dialog,

[image]

The installation needs to continue even if any download fails. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDP has `AllowContinue` option that allows continuing even on errors:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  idpSetOption('AllowContinue', '1');
end;
```

---

*Note that [Inno Setup 6.1](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.1-whatsnew.htm#6.1.0) has a native support for downloads. You may want to consider using it instead of IDP. See [Inno Setup: Install file from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887428/850848#66100456)*.

---

*Also, I believe that `UpdateReadyMemo` can be called multiple times (when the user returns from the "Ready" page). So your `idpAddFileSize` can also add the file to download queue multiple times.*