# InnoTools Downloader is failing with “Sorry, the files could not be downloaded”

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-tools-downloader

I have been attempting to make an installer for an application where the required files are on a server. I am using Inno Setup with InnoTools Downloader. After executing the setup I'm getting the following error:

> Sorry, the files could not be downloaded, Click 'Retry' or try downloading the files again, or click 'Next' to continue installing anyway.

The script was working fine but all of a sudden its throwing me this error, I don't know what am I doing wrong. I have attached the picture and code below.

[image: Error]

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var 
  i: Integer;
begin
   CreateTheWizardPages;
   for i := 1 to 10 do
   begin
     if down_URLs[i].url <> '' then 
       itd_addfile(down_URLs[i].url, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\'+down_URLs[i].target_exe));
   end;
   itd_downloadafter(wpReady);
end;
```

Any help either resolving this issue or pointing me to a solution would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found out, InnoTools Downloader does not support HTTPS. Instead of switching to an unencrypted HTTP, consider switching to [Inno Download Plugin](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/).

Inno Download Plugin support HTTPS, in addition to [other advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4426859/850848#47140085). It's kind of a drop-in replacement for InnoTools Downloader. Only few changes are required.

---

There is also [DwinsHs](https://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php). And [Inno Setup 6.1](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6-whatsnew.htm) supports downloads natively (including HTTPS). See [Inno Setup: Install file from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887428/850848#66100456).